# Laravel testing forms using Inertia

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, testing, inertiajs

I am trying to find the best method for testing forms in Laravel. I'm using Inertia and Laravel Fortify for user accounts.

If I run what I'm trying to test in the web browser it works as expected, however, when I run the test I'm getting a 419 status response with the error being: CSRF token mismatch.

According to documentation for Inertia in Laravel it handles CSRF protection for us (which I guess is why running this manually in the browser works): https://inertiajs.com/csrf-protection

Here's my current code to test registering an user:

```
        $response = $this->get('/register')
            ->assertStatus(200);

        $response = $this->json('POST', '/register', [
            'name' => 'Example Name',
            'email' => 'example@example.com',
            'password' => 'password',
            'password_confirmation' => 'password'
        ]);

        $response->assertCreated();
```

I 'm also not sure if this is the correct way to test a POST request from a form, so if this is wrong please suggest a better method to write a test for this, or if it is better to use Laravel Dusk to perform this kind of test by simulating the user filling out the form.

To find out it was a CSRF issue I ran:

```
$response->dump();
```

in the test.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you must use the `POST` method to submit your form.

An option to verify that your registration was successful is use `assertDatabaseHas()` with an array of user data.

```
$this->post('/register', [
    'name' => 'Example Name',
    'email' => 'example@example.com',
    'password' => 'password',
    'password_confirmation' => 'password'
])->assertStatus(302);

$this->assertDatabaseHas('users', [
    'name' => 'Example Name',
    'email' => 'example@example.com'
]);
```